# Puppeteer : How to install puppeteer on ec2 server

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, chromium, puppeteer

I want to install Puppeteer on ec2 server. So Do I need to install puppeteer and chromium on each machine on which I need to scrape data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll only need to install `puppeteer`. `puppeteer` auto-downloads a version of Chromium that works with it - everything works together out of the box!

So once you've got `puppeteer` installed, you're already good to go!

See the `puppeteer` readme for more info:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#readme

Comment: Thanks @AJC24. But I have one more doubt. After Installing Puppeteer on Server Does it install chromium on Server or Local Machine.

Comment: If you've done the installation directly on the server, then the server should have the Chromium installation too.

Comment: Then We need not to install chromium on Local Machine right?

Comment: Exactly. Everything will run from your server. If you want to run `puppeteer` on a machine, install `puppeteer` and then that machine has everything it needs. No need for any additional installations after that. So if you want `puppeteer` on your server but **not** your local machine, then you'll only need to install `puppeteer` on your server. That's it.

Comment: **I'm getting below error on EC2.**

/opt/casper_web/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-599821/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libXcomposite.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you sure your node installation has all the permissions it needs (ie. you didn't see any `EACCESS` errors during `npm install`)? Sounds like something that should have downloaded with the module is missing.

Comment: I ran this project locally, installed everything on my local machine which works fine for me, now I am planing to run this on server but I wonder 
1. for every client a different instance of puppeteer which opens a chromium will be there
2 every client needs to have puppeteer and chromium installed on their machine and my code can control those local instances on client machine

Comment: I am getting this error when launching puppeteer on EC2 instance `Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /root/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-114.0.5735.133/chrome-linux64/chrome ENOENT\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting\n`

Answer (score 1):

Installing puppeteer to an EC2 can be a tricky affair. There is another problem which hasn't been addressed.

To answer your question you don't have to worry about downloading Chromium separately as `npm i puppeteer` would take care of downloading the Chromium that's compatible with puppeteer and take care of the rest.

However, the more troublesome issue that you will run into is to make sure that the required dependencies are installed on the EC2 in order to run Puppeteer. These dependencies differ between distributions(CentOS, Ubuntu/Debian etc...).

Follow these steps,

1. Install all the dependencies required. You can refer this link for the list,
   https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix
2. After all the dependencies are installed, install `npm` and configure proxy in `.npmrc` if you are behind a VPC/proxy.
3. Then as usual go ahead with `npm i puppeteer` and proceed as always

Let me know if this works and reach out to me if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

When you install puppeteer , the chromium is installed automatically. The only thing that you need to take care of is , you should run it in a headless mode .. if you want to run it in non headless mode (i.e with GUI) you need to have a VNC server with EC2 and start the script through VNC. As far as you don't specifically need to run it in a non-headless mode all you need to do is

- `npm i`
- `npm start`

puppeteer ships with it's own chromium build.